# Можно ли сделать установщик Windows 8 из уже установленной системы?

Tags: windows, сборка

Есть два ISO - windows 8 b windows 8.1. Ghbxtv dnjhjt cnfdbncz njkmrj yf e;t ujnjde. Windows 8. 
Можно ли как-то полностью установить/настроить систему и все необходимые программы, а потом сделать образ из всего установленного, чтобы на чистыйй комп устанавливалось уже с необходимыми настройками и программами?

Нашел некоторые подобные инструменты, но они позволяют сделать свою сборку только с ISO. А у меня их два и кучка полезных программ.

P.S. А точнее как это проще всего сделать ламеру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет смысла. Винда не Линух: на машине с другим железом Вы получите "синий экран смерти". Есть, конечно, некоторые хитрости, но ими стоит заморачиваться если такие установки делаешь на крупном предприятии с большим количеством компов. А для бэкапа Вам хватит того, что описано ниже.
По теме:
Устанавливается винда, устанавливаются необходимые проги и т.п., после чего с помощью Norton Ghost (**версией не ниже 15!**) создается имидж Вашей операционки (обязательно с диском восстановления, который прим. 100 МБ - иначе работать не будет).
А Вы, видимо, смотрели программы делающие сборки-инсталляторы ОС. Тогда все правильно, что их выходной файл iso - ибо его надо будет записывать на CD/DVD.